# How to always show passwords typed into the terminal?

Tags: command-line, password

I use ubuntu to host my webserver, which I connect to through an SSH client (MobaXterm). Whenever I update it, I have to type in my password, usually multiple times. Ubuntu hides passwords that are being typed for security reasons. But I'm at home on my own computer, and no one is looking over my shoulder, so this feature is only a hindrance to me. Is there a way to turn it off so the password is always shown?

What I want is to just see the characters typed out like any other terminal command, rather than remaining invisible.

Comment: I recommend you **[edit]** with more info about what sort of solutions you'd accept: Must you see the password, or just placeholder characters like `*` so you always know how many characters you've typed? When you type your password on your local machine, are you usually doing so from a graphical terminal (like GNOME Terminal), and if so would it be sufficient to have a graphical dialog box come up in which you enter it, and if so would it be sufficient for placeholder characters to be shown in the dialog box? *Would just having Ubuntu automatically update itself solve the underlying problem?*

Comment: updated the post

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by editing a file `sudo nano /etc/sudoers.tmp`

Scroll down to the line `Defaults env_reset` and add `,pwfeedback`

Press Ctrl + o to save, Ctrl + x to exit.