# Show asterix while entering password in Terminal

Tags: command-line, password

In recent versions of Linux Mint, Asterix is shown for password characters in Terminal. In Ubuntu, nothing is shown for more security.

How to make characters in passwords appear as Asterix in Terminal in Ubuntu?

Unlike [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182726/how-to-always-show-passwords-typed-into-the-terminal), I don't want the password to be totally revealed.

Comment: (duped via https://askubuntu.com/questions/412292/enable-password-asterisks-when-run-command-sudo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a password prompt give feedback by showing asterisks while you are typing, provide the option `pwfeedback` to the sudoers plugin.

Copy this command, open a terminal and paste the following command:

```
echo -e "Defaults\tpwfeedback" | sudo tee -a /etc/sudoers.d/0pwfeedback
```

To undo the change, delete the file `/etc/sudoers.d/0pwfeedback`

```
sudo rm /etc/sudoers.d/0pwfeedback
```

Comment: Note that I changed the way to do it: I now provide a single command that places the option in a separate file under /etc/sudoers.d/. Much simpler, but also "cleaner":  this way, you do not overwrite a system installed config file that may be overwritten during a future update. This way is how Linux Mint does it. Also included how to undo the setting.